# If only six blocks are solved per hour, then how are more than six miners getting paid per hour?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, pool-payout-methods

According to this [page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block#What_if_I.27m_1.25_towards_calculating_a_block_and....3F) on average six blocks in the Bitcoin network are solved per hour, yet there are thousands of Bitcoin miners and presumably more than six of them are making money every hour. What am I missing?

Comment: Not a bad question actually, but it is surprising that you missed [tag:mining-pools]. :)

Comment: Thanks @Murch, I'm very noob and still putting the basics together

Comment: Sure thing. Perhaps you want to have a look at [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started/22840#22840); it collects a few questions that might be of interest to new users.