# Where do i get a good hands-on Bitcoin learning experience as a newbie?

Tags: api, trading, buy-bitcoins

I understand that bitcoin is a virtual form of money. It fascinates me. I have been to the site and seen numerous videos on youtube, but none seems to capture the vast enormity of the workings of bitcoin.

I would like to know how bitcoin is used, whether i can see the blockchain (since it is open source), how bitcoin to currency rates change, where and when and how bitcoin was created, why it is so successfull, if there is a way to see every step of a bitcoin transaction AND everything else that concerns the real life application of bitcoin.

I am a newbie, and i find most of the introductory documents of bitcoin working online too technical or too simple. How can i begin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/5406)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a duplicate question, but I'll try to be as helpful as I can.

First, go download bitcoind: https://bitcoin.org/en/download

Next, run bitcoin in regtest mode (-regtest): https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Try some commands that create transactions: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#transaction-tutorial

You should have a decent grasp of how bitcoin works from playing with that and can then proceed to read some more heavy-weight documentation: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-documentation

Answer (score 0):

Buy or download Mastering Bitcoin. The first chapters give an introduction to Bitcoin for those who are new. The next chapters go in more technical detail.

https://www.bitcoinbook.info/