# I am a motivated first timer in Hawaii! Looking for friend/mentor

Tags: faucets

I've set up a Blockchain account, because I've spent a couple days on all the Davi sets, researching and gaining all these satoshi, but my account balance is still current at zero. After all that work I thought I'd see something. I started microwallets, and been doing all things new. I could really appreciate someone to help walk me through some steps. I'll keep researching and I'm a voracious student. Many thanks

Comment: Hi DaKinealigns, welcome to Bitcoin.stackexchange.com! I've just invited you to our chat, if you want to shoot me a few questions, I'll be around for a couple more hours, I think. ;) Unfortunately, we don't allow calls for donations in posts and I can't discern a question, so I'll be editing your post in a moment. Meanwhile, perhaps you want to check out [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/5406). Cheers!

Comment: There appears to be a [Bitcoin group in Honolulu](https://www.meetup.com/HonoluluBitcoinGroup/), if you're anywhere near there, they have a meetup on the 27th. :)

Comment: Thank you for the information and edit! Will keep working to learn the lingo/systems in all its newness to me :)

Comment: You may also have received something at said address 0:-)

Comment: Yay!  I was wondering how it happened but figured my reaching out had something to do with ..thank you for helping me start!

Comment: See [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool). ;)