# Bitcoin Trading

Tags: bitcoind, trading, earnings

How can we trade Bitcoins? Please suggest any procedures that could I follow. I am a newbie in this field. I have just started researching about bitcoins. I don't know much about them, like how to earn them, what is the right place to find bitcoins, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin SE.  This is a very broad question.  How to trade will depend greatly your legal jurisdiction.  On top of that, you will want to learn about storing and transferring bitcoin.  This site is a great place to start, but you are unlikely to get a single answer that covers all of your questions.  I recommend figuring out the specific questions you have, searching the site for existing answers, and posting new questions if you can't find them.  Best of luck exploring the world of Bitcoin!

Comment: Thank you for help, however I just wanted to earn Bitcoins and trade them.

Comment: You might be interested in this related topic: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/5406)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I got good knowledge regarding Bitcoins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase bitcoin from various locations. As you're just starting out, I recommend coinbase. Coinbase is mainly used to easily purchase bitcoins by using credit card or bank transfer. Coinbase owns another website called GDAX, which is used for crypto-currency trarding. I recommend using this as well and get the hang of things like looking at charts to get to know the market. Once you have done so, you can do everything on GDAX, including buying and selling of bitcoin with USD. The good thing is, funds from coinbase and GDAX can be instantly transferred from one to the other.

I should mention that cryptocurrency is very volatile. Before you trade, I recommend you keep up to date with bitcoin news by going to certain places like reddit.com/r/bitcoin and you paper trade.

I hope this helps.