# how can i get and manage my bit coin?

Tags: wallet, client, exchanges

I really want to know how to get and manage my bit coin and how I can work with bit coin I also want to deal in bit coin and invest in bit coin.

Comment: I want to be a professional flute player, but I don't know anything about flutes so I should probably instead do something else. This really reads like a "What is bitcoin" question. Just punch "bitcoin" into your favorite search engine and learn as much as you can.

Comment: You might find [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/5406) useful.

Answer (score 3):

To “get” bitcoin:  use a service (google buy bitcoin) to exchange your fiat currency for bitcoin.

To “manage” bitcoin:  use a service (google bitcoin wallets) to set up a bitcoin wallet to store any bitcoin you own.  Be particularly careful not to transfer any coin to an incorrectly-typed bitcoin address because you will never see those coins again if you do.

To “invest” in bitcoin:  follow the first two points.  Congratulations, you’ve invested in bitcoin.

To “trade” or “make money from” bitcoin:  consider transferring your bitcoin to an exchange (google bitcoin exchanges).  Once you have an account which contains bitcoin at an exchange, you are able to choose whether to buy or sell at any point in time.  By chaining together these buy and sell activities in a patterns in alignment with an overall strategy, you may either increase the amount of bitcoin you have, or reduce it.

To really “mix things up”:  consider exchanging your bitcoin for other crypto currencies (google coinmarketcap), and trade other currencies.