# Am I Being Prodded By A Bitcoin Mining Scammer?

Tags: mining-reward, buy-bitcoins

I had someone approach me via an insta post, because i found his account and liked a photo. He said he was a bitcoin miner and forex trader in LA california, and asked if i was interested in earning returns daily. We exchanged whatsapp numbers and the conversation below happened (hopefully the pictures upload

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After this he led me through the process of downloading and setting up a wallet with the app BlockChain (popular trusted app right?) And showed me where the recieving wallet was. I shared my receiving wallet code with him. 
He then had me go on the site www.coinmama.com to buy bitcoin for my wallet.

I told him i would do this tomorrow, and am now trying to think the situation over.

Is there a scam around bitcoin mining that involves this process, and what should I be aware of?

I don’t plan on sharing my sending code to anyone, or my bank account. But if he knows my receiving code, is he planning on scamming all the money?

Many thanks for any replies. I have a nominal education on the exchanges but I have a head in me, and a massive scam detector.

Comment: He wants you to join him in the restroom?

Comment: Bitcoin mining is a real thing, and some people do make profits at it, if they have invested a lot of money in expensive hardware and found access to cheap (or stolen) electricity in some part of the world.  But the profits are not anything like the annual 600000% he's promising.

Answer (score 3):

This is **most certainly a scam**, the scammer's messages explaining  how Bitcoin works are pretty much nonsensical. Disregard all the jibberish he wrote to you, if you'd like to learn about Bitcoin, this is a great question to start with: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started).

DO NOT use the wallet you created with his help. Just forget you ever created it, if you want to learn to use Bitcoin, you **must** create a new wallet in the future.

There is a known scam where the scammer will 'assist' when setting up a wallet, and they will copy down a wallet 'seed phrase' that will let them re-create your wallet on a different computer later. It doesn't matter if you change your password, once they have the seed phrase they can have access to your coins.

Comment: thanks so much. i communicated with him today, and grilled the f*** out of the conversation. i asked for him to lay out the entire process. he wanted me to go to a website (cryptofuriouz.com) where i would set up an account and “invest” $500US worth of BTC, and he would “manage the account”.  i asked why HIS PHONENUMBER was on the contact page, and he’s like “Oh, i’m the only manager”. So i told him straight up he’s trying to get me to walk my money right to his wallet somehow. He gave up after that. Again, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @epc ah, I didn’t see the latter half of your comment, ignore my first reply. I’m glad you got away without being scammed, since scammers are usually good at making themselves look legit to laypeople. Bitcoin is interesting and exciting tech, but it is worth doing your own research to learn about how it works before jumping in. In any case, there is no legit bitcoin service that promises huge returns, be very wary of any situation like that. Happy to help :)