# Please guide what should i do

Tags: mining-theory

Am new in bitcoin world and didn't started it yet...
A man from USA saying to create blockchain wallet n top up then share ur email n wallet address not login not password to connect my wallet to a s9 machine for mining i 'll keep my money with me in my wallet he will create a node address to connect s9 ...I want know is it safe should I do it and if it's scam what is the real way to do it another question is mining profitable ?

Answer (score 3):

> connect my wallet to a s9 machine for mining ... is it safe

No. You will lose all your money. He will use your fear of losing your money to trick you into giving him more money (e.g. private-key release fees) and more money and more money until you have nothing left to give. Then he will tell you to borrow more money from your family, from the bank, from loan sharks ...

> if it's scam

It is a scam

> what is the real way to do it

Spend a long time (at least an hour a day for a couple of weeks) researching Bitcoin and mining. Don't proceed until you understand private-keys, public-keys, seed-phrases, recovery, different types of wallet, watch-only wallets, principles of mining and so on.

Read the answers to [all these questions](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fraud) to innoculate yourself against scammers

Then buy a hardware wallet or download a good stand-alone wallet.

Buy a small amount of Bitcoin from a well-known exchange

Practice recovery of your wallet as if your hardware-wallet or computer is stolen. Don't proceed until you have proven you can recover full control of your bitcoin only using the recovery phrase without touching your existing wallet hardware or computer or  mobile-phone.

Write down instructions for your family to recover your money if anything happens to you. Make them follow your written instructions without any help from you and see if they really can. If necessary create a new wallet with new keys and transfer all your Bitcoin to the new wallet. Update your saved recovery phrase etc.

Never share your wallet-password, recovery phrase or private-key with anyone (unless they are someone you'd be happy for them to walk away with everything you own tomorrow). Never let anyone else log in or remotely access your computer or your wallet to help you, even if they seem to be the most honest person in the world, especially if they suggest you can secure your wallet afterwards by changing a password.

After becoming comfortable buying and using bitcoin for several months, re-think about mining, if you have a few thousand dollars you can afford to lose totally, you are probably ready to consider whether the process is for you.

> is mining profitable ?

Not unless you already have several thousand dollars to invest in ASIC mining equipment and a good source of cheap electricity in a building with very good air-conditioning and where noise does not matter. This isn't suitable for people new to Bitcoin. You must be prepared to lose that money without hardship.

Answer (score 1):

> A man from USA saying to create blockchain wallet n top up then share ur email n wallet address not login not password to connect my wallet to a s9 machine for mining i 'll keep my money with me in my wallet he will create a node address to connect s9

To be clear: this is **absolute nonsense**, what he is describing has NOTHING to do with how mining actually works. He is just trying to scam you by gaining access to your wallet.

I suggest taking a look at this question: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started)