# I had someone offer to mine bitcoin for me, I am a beginner

Tags: buy-bitcoins, fraud

I had someone offer to mine bitcoin for me. I pay for the bitcoin on cash app and he mines it for me. With messaging him I started to feel like he didn't really know what he was talking about when telling me to sign up for cash app and coinbase. I followed what he said but during signing up on the 2 sites but it was like he didn't know what he was talking about during the time I had to wait for both account to be verified with 2 small cents deposits into my bank account. But he was telling me miss information on what to do an it didn't make any sense. Cause the sites were basically saying I can't move forward until i enter in the 2 amounts. But had to screenshot the pages to show what they said and had to write it all out for him exactly how it showed on the sight. and after a few minutes he finally understood me. But it feel like he didn't even know how to sign up process went which is suspicious to me an I don't want to get caught in a scam

Comment: Yes, this is a scam. Do not follow the scammers advice, do not send them any more information, and definitely do not send them any bitcoin. If you're interested in Bitcoin, this is a good starting point: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started

Comment: The "small deposits" thing is often a way to authorize another bank account to be "linked" with yours.  It's very likely that the scammer now has the ability to **withdraw** money from your bank account, even if your intention was only to let him deposit money.  You should notify your bank of what happened and close the account immediately, and hope that the scammer hasn't yet had a chance to take all your money out.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there are a lot of scammers around. Don't pay to anyone you don't know (and before you sign up on an exchange, make sure it's a reputable one).

There are also some services which allow you to buy "a miner" which mines for you, but generally, you would be better off just directly buying whatever coin you want yourself.

**Be careful, don't trust strangers.**