# Merging cryptocurrency wallets

Tags: paper-wallet

In my quest to learn about cryorocurrency, as fast as I possibly can, I have registered with about seven wallets, all with one goal, to deposit Bitcoin into one of them, I am yet to do this but I was thinking that maybe working with only one wallet would be easier, anyone, can you PLEASE help ?

Answer (score 1):

You should find a wallet which gives you control of your keys (non custodial, not a ‘web wallet’ with an online login, etc). This will give you **full** responsibility over your coins, be sure that you safely store a backup (‘seed phrase’) so that you can recover your coins in case of loss.

If you created a wallet but did not use it to store coins, then do not give a second thought to just abandoning it. Do not attempt to ‘combine’ wallets either, this is counter to how they were designed to be used, and it could have very undesirable affects on your wallet security, etc. Just find some software you like and trust, and use it.

[This site lists a number of wallet software options](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet), you’ll need to do your own research to figure out which which one will suit your needs best.

This question is a great place for new users to get info: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/63872)