# How can I generate thousands of receiving addresses from a Bitcoin wallet?

Tags: address, address-generation

I want to generate thousands of receiving addresses without sending any BTC to another wallet. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Using what client software?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you have an [HD wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet) which is free you can generate an unlimited amount of receiving addresses.

There is lots of services offering HD wallet, hardware, mobile or desktop, electrum is a common one, you just have to download and install it, choose and save your secret phrase then you can begin generating your addresses from your seed: https://electrum.org/#download

Comment: I got about 120 receiving addresses from my Electrum wallet. How can I generate more?

Comment: Addresses will keep being generated as you go, but if you want to force it take a look at this site https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1741383.0 I see a comment "If you want more than 20 addresses showing in your wallet then open the "console" tab and type the commands below into it. Press your enter key after writing each line.

wallet.storage.put('gap_limit', 50)
wallet.storage.write()" So I suggest putting 1000 instead of 50 there

Comment: Is possible generate it also with the Bitcoin core

Comment: Yes, it is a  HD wallet by default since bitcoin-core 13.0, here is how: with bitcoin-qt go to "Receive" then clic on "Request payment" it will generate a new addresses each time.

Comment: or with bitcoin-cli just use getnewaddress I suggest you go to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22840/95422 to learn more about bitcoin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate as many numbers of addresses. [Bitcoinjs Library](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/) or [Iancoleman Resource](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest method if you're okay generating a new wallet is using the Bulk Wallet tab on bitaddress.org. You generate a wallet, then use the Bulk Wallet tab to generate as many address/key pairs as you want.

Comment: This is a terrible idea - you should never use a random third party system to generate keys, especially an online one.

Comment: You can download the code from Github (https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org), check the code, and run it locally on a computer without an Internet connection.