# Hello, i wanna help?

Tags: wallet, sending, money

I have question and problem. Im from Poland, installed Bitcoin Core, wanna send money from my bank account in Poland to my bitcoin core wallet, but how i can do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started). Since złoty are not Bitcoin, you first need to exchange złoty to Bitcoin at a currency exchange. This is the same as buying Bitcoin using złoty. You can do this in person or online if you can find a reliable person, Bitcoin machine or online exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send anything other than bitcoin to (or out of) your Bitcoin Core wallet. You'd need to acquire bitcoin somewhere else first, then you will be able to send it to your Bitcoin Core wallet.