# how can i get back money from my electronic wallet

Tags: wallet

I am new to bitcoin and someone (the account manager) call me to buy and i made it last week. However, when i asked the account manager to transfer the money back to my credit card account. They said they have to make it to a mirror transaction first and then need to debit my credit card again. Now, i am no more money in my saving and credit card account and just saw my electronic wallet with money. How can i cash those out from it and transfer back to my credit card account? please help. In fact, i dont know how to operation my electronic wallet.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely sounds like a scam.

> I am new to bitcoin and someone (the account manager) call me to buy and i made it last week

Bitcoin does not have 'account managers'. There is a well-known scam though, where the scammer will message/contact you pretending to be an investor/manager/miner/etc, offering amazing returns on your investment in BTC. If someone is offering large guaranteed profits, it is almost certainly a scam.

> They said they have to make it to a mirror transaction first and then need to debit my credit card again

Bitcoin does not work this way, and neither do credit cards. There is no such thing as a bitcoin 'mirror transaction'. The scammer simply wants you to send them more money. **Do not send them more money.**

> just saw my electronic wallet with money

This is part of the scam. The bitcoin blockchain is a public record, anyone can view and verify the apparent balance of an address, but only the person with the private keys for that address actually owns those coins (ie, can spend them). "Watch-only wallets" let you track the balance of *any* address of your choosing. The scammer will often show their victim a "watch-only" wallet to trick the victim into thinking they own that bitcoin. They do not own that bitcoin. The scammer may not even own that bitcoin. It is a mirage.

Also, there are no fees related in obtaining private keys. That is another tactic used by the scammers (eg. "please pay us a fee so that we can activate the private key").

> How can i cash those out from it and transfer back to my credit card account? please help.

Your money is likely gone. You can report the crime to the relevant authorities if you so desire.

> In fact, i dont know how to operation my electronic wallet.

Bitcoin is a really interesting and revolutionary thing, but you should take some time to learn about it before you start investing in it. This question is a good place to start: [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started)

Comment: Thank you sir. I actually stop to make payment to them but before action taken, all my active money at bank are totally cash out. poor.

Comment: @Vicky: Report the fraud to police but don't expect them to get your money back for you. Do not accept s help from anyone who says they can get your money back. Many fraudsters/thieves/conmen/criminals will contact you offering to help - but they will later pressure you into paying "recovery fees" and other fees they invent to get money out of you.

Comment: I'd report it quickly to your bank, maybe they have a chance to return something. In case you got any mails with Bitcoin addresses or transactions please advise. Some scammers really buy bitcoin because it's more difficult to run away with dollars. These bitcoin transactions can sometimes be traced until cash out at an exchange. If this is successfully the next hurdle are the involved jurisdictions.