# Is there no Gmail required to receive Bitcoin payment from another company?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I don't fully understand how to receive payment, there is no Gmail address space, how can I get my address for business transaction, I mean which address will I use to receive payment?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask about. Which service are you talking about? What does gmail have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

To receive Bitcoin, you don't need a Gmail address or any sort of email address.

What you need is a large random looking number called a Bitcoin-address. This number can be produced from another large number that is kept secret by you and is called a private-key. You can create these numbers using any of many different software programs called [Bitcoin wallets](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

See [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/13866)