# Where do I get my Bitcoin address

Tags: wallet

How do I get my address so someone can send me bitcoin. I am new to this and trying to get paid from an entity that only uses Bitcoin.

Comment: What wallet are you using?

Comment: what exchanges operate in your jurisdiction?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a Bitcoin wallet, [choose one](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)

Many wallets have a `Receive` button you can click to generate a fresh address that you can give to someone so they can send money.

Exact details depend on which wallet software you are using.

---

See also

- [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22796/13866)